# Deleting Scheduled Job versus Aborting job?

Tags: asynchronous

What will happen if the scheduled job is deleted and what happen if it is aborted.

Do we have any significant difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that the deleted job will no longer appear in any list view, while an aborted job will still be listed in list views. Either way, the job will no longer run.

Comment: thank you!! sfdcfox

Comment: class is already scheduled, How can we get the jobid for the same ?

Comment: @Vineel AsyncApexJob has a ApexClassId field that you can use to find all instances of scheduled jobs for a class.